# How to check if my monitor is on?

Tags: remote-access, monitor, acpi

I usually connect to my computer in the university using team viewer. Is there any way (for example using [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)) to determine if my monitor is on (i.e., other one can see it)? I have no web cam there.  Its operating system is Windows 7 - 64 bit.

Comment: Why not just unplug the monitor before you leave?

Comment: Sometimes the power gets lost and I have to ask my friend to start my computer again. So, it is better to be a simple task!

Comment: There's a good article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12794/Complete-Guide-on-How-To-Turn-A-Monitor-On-Off-Sta) about manipulating the monitor status.